# Asp.net mvc membership always return false in `ValidateUser`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

**Question#1**

I have my running site on mvc3 now i decided to make copy of that and create a new project after that i copy all logic which i want to move in Account Controller of new project now when i enter any credentials and click on logon .

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
 {
 }
```

This method never return true even if my credentials are right . Whats the matter .

**Question#2**

When we create new project of asp.net mvc3 we got automatically two controllers Home and Account , How should i create a user info table according to default asp.net mvc3 membership . Or please guide me if there is any default script for this thing .

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

This is how i create user

```
 MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(userName, "1234567", email);
```

Comment: how did you `create` your users?

Comment: that looks solid. what happens when you try to login? have you tried creating users with the VS website admin tool?

Comment: What is ***MembershipService*** class? Is it a ***Custom Membership Provider***?